# How to copy file in Ubuntu One API

Tags: ubuntu-one-api

Is it possible to copy file from one folder to another with UbuntuOne API?
In this manual https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud/ there is nothing about ways to copy file.

Answer (score 3):

No, the v1 API does not provide the ability to copy existing file. Only renaming a file is supported.